# Unable to launch AVD in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-virtual-device

This problem seems to only happen for a specific project I have saved on my desktop which was cloned from GitHub.

Clicking on Run > Run Without Debugging, I am prompted to "Select a device to use". This is unusual, because usually, VSC provides the android devices I have downloaded on Android Studio as possible suggestions - however I don't see this.

Running the command: Flutter: Launch Emulator, I am able to choose an android device. However, after VSC launches the device, it displays the message: "Waiting for Pixel 3a API 29 to connect"

60 seconds later it gives the following error: "Failed to launch Pixel 3a API 29: Error. Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds."

I only seem to have this problem with this flutter project. Creating a new project, I am able to connect to my AVD. I have tried removing and cloning the repository from GitHub to my desktop several times however I end up with the same error.

Edit: Yes, I have tried stopping and wiping the data of the AVD, however this doesn't work either.

Comment: did you try to restart the AVD and then try again?